# Compare the two array and set the value to True if value found in another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

I have two arrays
A = [1,5,9,12,14] and B = [16,4,8,12]
both the arrays have the different length. I want to compare the array A with B. If the value of array  A is available in B then don't do anything else add it to sheet.
Below is my code for same but I am not getting desired output.
can anybody help me on the same?

```
function updateTicketsAreNotInDeploymentDoc() {
  var A = getJiraNoFromJira();
  var B = getJiraNoFromDoc();
  for(var i = 0; i<A.length; i++) {
    var data = new Array();
    for(var j=0; j<B.length; j++) {
      if(A[i] == B[j]) {
        Logger.log("found="+A[i]);
      }
    } 
    data.push(A[i]);
  }  

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(RESULTANT_DEPLOYMENT_SHEET);
  sheet.appendRow(data);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Sheet.appendRow() method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendRow(Object)) only accept mono dimensionnal array, cause it's only add one row after the sheet. You must go through your list to append the data. As say on the documentation:

> Appends a row to the spreadsheet. This operation is atomic; it
>   prevents issues where a user asks for **the last row**, and then
>   writes to **that row**, and an intervening mutation occurs between
>   getting **the last row** and writing to it.

Here is a sample of code:

***Edit:*** As @charlietfl point it, there's is other problem before: you instanciate your data array each time you loop on your A array.

*The code as being modify to correct this.*

```
function updateTicketsAreNotInDeploymentDoc() {
  var A = getJiraNoFromJira();
  var B = getJiraNoFromDoc();
  var data = new Array();
  for(var i = 0; i<A.length; i++) {
    var Found = false;
    for(var j=0; j<B.length; j++) {
      if(A[i] == B[j]) {
        Logger.log("found="+A[i]); 
        Found = true;
      }
    } 
    if(Found == false){
      data.push(A[i]);
    }
  }  

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(RESULTANT_DEPLOYMENT_SHEET);

  for(var k = 0; k<data.length; k++){
    sheet.appendRow([data[k]]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Several other problems before that also

Comment: @charlietfl:please tell me what are all other problems?

Comment: @charlietfl : You're right. I've see it after you've right your comment. I add some correction on edit.

Comment: @Pierre-MarieRichard: I don't want to do anything if the value of array A is exist in Array B

Comment: @SaurabhGarg My bad, misread some word. I've modify the feature to write the missing value from A on B array.

Comment: @Pierre-MarieRichard Thanks Dude

Answer (score 0):

Here's the quicker version, just for fun :p
The performance difference with big arrays (beyond 30k elements) is serious.

```
function compareArrays()
{
  var obj = {};
  var result = [];
  var A = [1,5,9,12,14];
  var B = [16,4,8,12];

  for (var i = 0; i < A.length; ++i)
  {
    obj[A[i]] = true;
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < B.length; ++i)
  {
    if (obj[B[i]] == undefined)
    {
      result.push([B[i]]);
    }
  }
  SpreadsheetApp.openById("id").getRange("A1:A" + result.length).setValues(result);
}
```